# Cluster analysis in R: optimal clustering when NO ALGORITHM WAS APPLIED

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I would like to be able to compare different clusterings with each other without having a ground truth.

The clustering code is:

```
threshold <- 0.9
df$cluster_9 <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(abs(cor(t(df))) > threshold) %>% 
  components() %>%
  membership() %>%
  as.vector()
```

I would like to run this code with different thresholds and be able to determine which threshold was the best.

For this I could calculate the adjusted R2 of clusters with different thresholds but without a target clustering I am missing the idea on how to calculate it.

Comment: You need a clustering method defining how to group the nodes of a graph into clusters. I do not see such a method like `hclust` or `kmeans` in your code. Or do you want to compare the dendrograms?

Comment: @danlooo I didn't use any of this methods. I manually clustered the instances that have a correlation higher than 0.9. That is the clustering method

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table with one threshold per row and then create columns for the components vector and a metric to assess (e.g. number of clusters):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(igraph)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'igraph'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     as_data_frame, groups, union
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     compose, simplify
#> The following object is masked from 'package:tidyr':
#> 
#>     crossing
#> The following object is masked from 'package:tibble':
#> 
#>     as_data_frame
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     decompose, spectrum
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     union

df <-
  diamonds %>%
  select(where(is.numeric)) %>%
  head(10)


tibble(threshold = seq(0, 1, by = 0.1)) %>%
  mutate(
    clustering = threshold %>% map(~ {
      graph_from_adjacency_matrix(abs(cor(df)) > .x) %>%
        components() %>%
        membership() %>%
        as.vector()
    }),
    n_clusters = clustering %>% map_int(~ .x %>%
      unique() %>%
      length())
  )
#> # A tibble: 11 x 3
#>    threshold clustering n_clusters
#>        <dbl> <list>          <int>
#>  1       0   <dbl [7]>           1
#>  2       0.1 <dbl [7]>           1
#>  3       0.2 <dbl [7]>           1
#>  4       0.3 <dbl [7]>           1
#>  5       0.4 <dbl [7]>           1
#>  6       0.5 <dbl [7]>           1
#>  7       0.6 <dbl [7]>           3
#>  8       0.7 <dbl [7]>           4
#>  9       0.8 <dbl [7]>           4
#> 10       0.9 <dbl [7]>           4
#> 11       1   <dbl [7]>           7
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: That is already a good start but what I would like to do is analyze the goodness of the clustering with different thresholds. The n_cluster does not say anything about the quality. How could I integrate in your code an adjusted R2 measure for example?

Comment: R2 is a property of a linear model and relates to the correlation of two variables. Since you do not have a ground truth I'm wondering what your second variable will be. I'm also not aware of any R2 metric here. Why not just using traditional metrics like the silhouette score?

Comment: Hey @danlooo, how would the code look like if I apply the silhouette score in your code to automatically choosing the best threshold for the clustering?